# Ubuntu 21.10 Thunderbird - selecting new email message, looses focus from contents pane

Tags: thunderbird, 21.10

**Thunderbird 91.3.1**

In `Thunderbird`, when reviewing incoming email, it **USED** to be that I could click on the subject line of any email message, and then without moving the mouse pointer, I could scroll my mouse wheel, and the message content would scroll.

Now what's happening, most of the time, but not always, after clicking on the subject line of any email message, I must manually click in the message content pane, before I can scroll the content.

This seems to have started with Ubuntu 21.10 and `Thunderbird` 91.3.1.

Anybody else seeing this same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone, I have this problem too, and I currently have Thunderbird 91.8.1 running on Windows 10.  I actually noticed this a while ago, probably about the same time you did, but initially ignored the inconvenience.

Some observations.

- If I click a message in the message list then immediately move the mouse to the message content area (preview pane) and start scrolling, either continuously, or scroll pause 1 second and scroll and repeat, scrolling NEVER starts working.
- If I click a message and move the mouse to the content area, but delay a few seconds, then scrolling works.  The amount of delay seems related to the complexity of the message.  One "smaller" html message takes a few seconds before it will scroll, a larger one takes 5 or more seconds.  A text-only email scrolls immediately.

Surprisingly, a short message that completely fits the window just never starts scrolling (humor).

Some technical interpretations.

- Scrolling cannot occur until a message content has been rendered internally in some way.  Note that visual rendering (i.e. seeing the email) occurs immediately, this pre-scrolling delay is something else.
- That internal rendering cannot start until some kind of short "quiet time" in the window - immediately moving the mouse to the content window and starting scrolling actually prevents that internal rendering, and thereby prevents the scrolling that you are ineffectively trying to perform just then.

I realize your description included scrolling with the mouse sitting on the message in the message list pane.  Mine has never scrolled that way, but I'm sure this is an OS thing having to do with which window and which dialog in that window receives the mouse scrolling commands.

Also, my scrolling works without clicking in the content pane, but just positioning the mouse in that pane (and delaying a few seconds).

I'm sure those differences are just OS platform differences, and that we have the same underlying Thunderbird scrolling issue.

PS - This question would probably get a better response if posted on https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1375799